# How to adopt test driven development in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, tdd, zend-framework2

I have basic knowledge of test driven development, from what I've read it has a lot benefits. I want to know how I can go adopting it in my Zend Framework 2 application (using MVC approach, Doctrine ORM, PHP 5.3).

From what I've read, each controller and model in the application will have a corresponding file containing methods that test the methods in the actual controllers and models. How do I set this up and how do I automate this?

Comment: GOOGLE and Offical Documentation are your best partner

Comment: You are way too broad here. You ask for any guidance in whatever format. Please be specific with your question. Have you performed TDD before? Have you used tests before? Are you familiar with phpunit? Have you written your own tests before? What is the key thing you struggle now with?

Comment: I've never used tests before, I've never written my own tests before. I don't know where to start.

Comment: TRY using Skeleton APP from Officail Site it has Test Driven Examples

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to dive into the deep end. Before you go about testing an application in a specific application framework you should first learn about testing and TDD in general. I would suggest beginning with a book about the basics like Kent Becks "Test Driven Development by Example".